# How to create CSV's from data frame row values in python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, for-loop

I have a data frame that has a row type that has A,B,C in repeated ways and they belong to different values an example below

```
Type Value Volume brand 
A     1     5      E
B     2     1      $
C     3     1      5 
C     2     1      2  
C     4     5      7 
B     2     1      E
A     3     3      $
```

The outcome I am searching for is to produce a CSV for A B and C

A.csv =

```
Type Value Volume Brand
A     1      5      E
A     3      3      $
```

B.csv =

```
Type Value Volume Brand
 B     2      1      $
 B     2      1      E
```

C.csv =

```
Type Value Volume Brand
 C     3     1      5 
 C     2     1      2  
 C     4     5      7
```

I know how to do this individually but I would like to learn a way to do this for all of them together like with a for because I have a data frame with 32 different types and doing them individually is not cost effficient so any help would be very valuable.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this:

```
week_grouped = df.groupby('Type')

for name, group in week_grouped:
    print(name) # to get names of your group in this case A, B , C
    group.to_csv(f'{name}.csv')
```

check using

```
df_A=pd.read_csv('A.csv', index_col=0)
```